# CalendarDatePicker has two shades background

Tags: c#, xaml

I am having a problem with my calendardatepicker. My calendardatepicker is located in a custom dialog and when the calendar is open the background has two colors and I don't know how to solve it. I am new to XAML.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by adding custom style to the calendar.

```
<Style x:Key="CalendarDatePickerStyle1" TargetType="CalendarDatePicker">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource CalendarDatePickerBorderThemeThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="CalendarDatePicker">
                    <Grid x:Name="Root" Background="Black">
                        <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                            <Flyout Placement="Bottom">
                                <Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
                                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Template">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
                                                    <ContentPresenter BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </Style>
                                </Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                                <CalendarView x:Name="CalendarView" OutOfScopeBackground="White" CalendarItemBackground="White" BlackoutForeground="White" CalendarIdentifier="{TemplateBinding CalendarIdentifier}" DisplayMode="{TemplateBinding DisplayMode}" DayOfWeekFormat="{TemplateBinding DayOfWeekFormat}" FirstDayOfWeek="{TemplateBinding FirstDayOfWeek}" IsTodayHighlighted="{TemplateBinding IsTodayHighlighted}" IsGroupLabelVisible="{TemplateBinding IsGroupLabelVisible}" IsOutOfScopeEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsOutOfScopeEnabled}" MinDate="{TemplateBinding MinDate}" MaxDate="{TemplateBinding MaxDate}" Style="{TemplateBinding CalendarViewStyle}"/>
                            </Flyout>
                        </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="32"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="32"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Gray"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="LightGray"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Gray"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="LightGray"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="LightGray"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Gray"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="DateText">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Gray"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="CalendarGlyph">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Gray"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="DateText">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter  x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Margin="{ThemeResource ComboBoxHeaderThemeMargin}" Visibility="Collapsed" x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"/>
                        <Border x:Name="Background"  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="DateText" Foreground="Black" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="12, 0, 0, 2" Grid.Row="1" Text="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <FontIcon x:Name="CalendarGlyph" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}" FontSize="16" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Glyph="&#xE787;" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```